# Pytest in python2 and python3 - different behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a project with the following structure

```
 -project
 --src
 --test
```

when i run pytest inside project folder from python2 (`python2 -m pytest`), it works fine, however, with python 3 (`python3 -m pytest`), i have an error in the test files as it cant find the imports in the src folder

I have an `__init__.py` in both folders

Is there any reason why it should be different in python2 and python3? How could i make it work in python3?

Thanks

Comment: did you install pytest using pip?

Comment: yes, its how i usually instal packages

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided details about exact import error, but probably you are using relative imports, which behaves differently in Python 2 and 3. If that's the case, try to use absolute imports.